# Raspbian display position calibration of the origin

Tags: raspbian

A new rpi 3B+ was outfitted with Raspbian.  For some reason, the `origin` (assume pixel at 0,0 is the upper left corner of display) is off the screen and the upper-half of the command bar is not visible.

Where are the Raspbian controls to calibrate the display: move the `origin`to its proper location in the upper-left corner?

## UPDATE

I tinkered with raspi-config and tried several settings. Which did not seem to help. After, I rebooted and somehow the origin is correct. That being said, the question stands: Where is the location of calibration controls within Raspbian?

Comment: This may be caused by **overscan**, did you try disabling it ?
run raspi-config 
then select Advanced Options -> Overscan -> Disable

Comment: @amaud I tinkered with `raspi-config` and tried several settings.  Which did not seem to help.  After, I rebooted and somehow the `origin` was correct

Comment: If your question has a solution then please make an answer. It will finish the question and show others that it has a solution and they does not try to help you for nothing.

Comment: @Ingo I agree with what your request, however, the question regarding the location of the calibration control has not been answered.